# How can this def statement get more compact?

Tags: python, function

Gets list with dict as input. Keys from the dict are scores.
Output is a list with scores from high to low.

```
def sort_scores(self, data):
        scores = []
        for i in data:
            scores = scores + list(map(lambda score_str: int(score_str), i.keys()))
        sorted_scores = list(map(lambda score_int: str(score_int), reversed(sorted(scores))))
        return sorted_scores
```

Comment: Why does it need to be more compact? If you have **working code** you think could be improved (more than just a single function), see [codereview.se].

Comment: Also, by "def statement", do you mean *function*?

Comment: I don't understand what you want but you can simply achieve your target by this: return data.keys.sort()

Comment: sorry sort doesn't return anything try this. data.keys.sort() return data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to shorten this:

```
map(lambda score_str: int(score_str), i.keys())
```

The expression `lambda score_str: int(score_str)` could just be written as `int`, no need to map a `lambda` if all you are doing is calling the function.

If you want to iterate over the dictionary don't bother calling `i.keys()`, just use `i`.

That gives you:

```
list(map(int, i))
```

but it reads more easily (albeit slightly longer) if you use a list comprehension:

```
scores = scores + [int(score_str) for score_str in i]
```

Also you can nest the for loop inside the list comprehension, but shorter is not always better so I'd advise against that.

```
scores = [int(score_str) for i in data for score_str in i]
```

The same applies to the last part:

```
sorted_scores = list(map(lambda score_int: str(score_int), reversed(sorted(scores))))
```

can just be:

```
 sorted_scores = [ str(score_int) for score_int in sorted(scores, reverse=True)]
```

You should get into the habit of using the `reverse` parameter when sorting, it doesn't matter here but there are situations when reverse sorting is not the same as sorting and reversing.

Also, you could avoid the casting by using the `key` parameter on the `sort`:

```
scores = [score_str for i in data for score_str in i]
sorted_scores = sorted(scores, reverse=True, key=int)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it's best to avoid using map & lambda, it produces very unreadable code. List comprehension is the way to go in Python.

Here's the same code in 3 very readable lines (you don't need a function for this)

```
scores = sorted([int(score_str)
                 for i in data
                 for score_str in i], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Close, but the `.sort()` method returns None so you just threw away the data!

Comment: Instead of using `.sort()` (which returns None) you could use the function `sorted(list)` which returns a sorted list.